# Ember.js: Changing property from another controller doesn't update template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm building restaurant managing app. I have two different controllers. The one who handles popup editor:

```
App.DishPopupController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  dishId: -1
  dish: null
  isHidden: false

  # always triggers when dishId is updated from DishController
  fetchModel: (->
    @set('dish', @store.find('dish', @get('dishId')))
    ).observes('dishId').on('init')

  # always triggers when isHidden is updated from DishController
  showPopup: (->
    console.log 'Updated!'
    ).observes('isHidden').on('init')

  actions:
    hidePopup: ->
      @set('isHidden', true)
```

and many controllers that handle dishes

```
App.DishController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  needs: ['dishPopup']
  isEditing: false

  actions: 
    acceptChanges: ->
      $(document.activeElement).blur()
      @set('name', @get('name').trim())
      @get('model').save()

    removeDish: ->
      if confirm 'Remove dish?'
        dish = @get('model')
        dish.deleteRecord()
        dish.save()

    showDishPopup: ->
      @set('controllers.dishPopup.isHidden', false)
      @set('controllers.dishPopup.dishId', @get('model.id'))
      @set('isEditing', true)

    acceptEdits: ->
      @set('isEditing', false)
      @get('model').save()
```

here is the template (written in Hamlbars):

```
// Dish popup
%script(type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="dish-popup")
  %div{:_action => 'hidePopup on="click"', :bind => {:class => ":dish-popup isHidden:hidden"}}
    =hb 'dish.name'
    %br
    =hb 'dish.price'
    %br 
    =hb 'dish.weight'
```

When I click on pop-up it hides as it should and templates updates, but when I trigger `showDishPopup` in `DishController` it doesn't update template and doesn't remove `hidden` class from `dish-popup`, although it triggers observer `showPopup`. Why is that? Can I update properties from another controller or I should not do it at all?

Comment: Is `dishPopup` a singleton?

Comment: if you output `controllers.dishPopup.isHidden` in `showDishPopup` does it show as true? (before setting it)

Comment: @kingpin2k yes, it is!

Comment: if you inject isHidden into the template, just the value, does it toggle, above the div?

Comment: @kingpin2k it doesn't...

Comment: @kingpin2k after all, is this ok to change some values in some controller from another one?

Comment: @kingpin2k `if you output controllers.dishPopup.isHidden in showDishPopup does it show as true?` I was wrong. It doesn't show true before. It shows false before and after setting, but I have no idea why it goes this way. Maybe it takes another instance of a controller?

Comment: @kingpin2k the problem must be in `@set('controllers.dishPopup.isHidden', false)`. This is very strange, but it seems to use another instance of a controller. When I type in a console `App.__container__.lookup('controller:dishPopup').get('isHidden');` it returns `false`, but Ember Chrome extension shows me `true`. Do you know how to get right instance of a controller?